# Как определить если ли заданная строка в тексте?

Tags: php

Например: строка `y1994` в строке `d17m5y1994`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
substr_count()
```

Синтаксис:

```
int substr_count(string haystack, string needle)
```

Функция substr_count() находит количество вхождений фрагмента в строку. Она возвращает число фрагментов needle, присутствующих в строке haystack.

```
strrpos()
```

Синтаксис:

```
string strrpos(string haystack, string needle)
```

Эта функция ищет в строке haystack последнюю позицию, где встречается символ needle.

Comment: $yi = "y1994"; $ubirthday = $_SESSION['birthday']; $str = substr_count($ubirthday,$yi); if($str === 1){ echo"<option selected value=\"y$i\"> $i </option>";}else{ echo"<option value=\"y$i\"> $i </option>"; }
я придумал вот такое решение, но оно не работает. В чём ошибка?( $_session['birthday'] = d17m5y1994 )

Comment: Ну тут в обоих вариантах выводится одно и тоже в if и else блоке и еще три знака равно подряд меня смущают. Чтобы отформатировать код сделайте отступ в 4 пробела и пропустите одну строку.

Comment: там в if блоке есть selected

Answer (score 1):

[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) не подойдёт?

Answer (score 0):

`$substr_exists = (strpos('d17m5y1994', 'y1994') !== false);`